# How to write tests for Stripe's `RateLimitError` and `StripePermissionError` errors?

Tags: javascript, testing, stripe-payments, rate-limiting

How can I test for Stripe's `RateLimitError` and `StripePermissionError` in my server's js Stripe tests?. What's the best way to do this?

I was hoping to find something in Stripe's [Testing for specific responses and errors documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses) like how you can use `tok_chargeDeclined` to simulate a declined charge. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find anything, and there are limited results when googling this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use Nock https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock, it will let you intercept the http request, and simulate a specific response. Find the specific endpoint that method in the stripe SDK calls into, then provide an error response matching stripe. That should provide you a good base for testing.

Comment: This is spot on for testing rate limiting. I ended up reaching out to Stripe's support and they suggested Nock as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Direct from Stripe's Support:

- `RateLimitError` - There is no predefined token you can use to test that particular error code. It’s quite rare for anyone to hit our rate limit. However, if you’d still like to be on the safe side (or get to that 100% code coverage), you could mock a 429 HTTP response using a library like nock.
- `StripePermissionError` - You can mock this by creating a test API key with limited permissions in your Stripe dashboard. In “API keys” under the “Developer” section on the left sideboard, you’ll find a “Restricted keys” section. Here you can create a key that only has access to charges. Then when you try and create a customer with your new test key you’ll receive a 403 HTTP error response with an error message.

A sample 403 error:

```
{
  error: {
    message: "The provided key 'rk_test_123' does not have the required permissions for this endpoint on account 'acct_123'. Having the 'rak_customer_write' permission would allow this request to continue.",
    type: "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```